# Git repo as Hg subrepo

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

Please explain me an exact right way to add git repository to hg repository as subrepository.

I just need to possibility to

1. clone hg repository with all its subrepositories (git and hg);
2. include *no* source code from subrepo to parent repo, because of subrepo already have its own (git) repo and develops apart from me.

I've tried some things and I am really disoriented now. Should I create hg subrepo to hold git subrepo? What revision directs `.hgsubstate` (hg or git) to? Should I commit git code to hg subrepo and why?

Now I am trying to embed https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup into https://bitbucket.org/cube54/mavemples/src. At this moment on bitbucket this task looks done, but when I clone parent (mavemples) repo, it creates empty hg subrepo in my working directory.

My `.hgsub`:

```
GWT_multiple_apps = GWT_multiple_apps

[subpaths]
GWT_multiple_apps = git://git@bitbucket.org:espinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup.git
```

My `.hgsubstate`:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 GWT_multiple_apps
```

So when on bitbucket I click on revision number, I get 404 error, because revision 000000000000 of git repo does not exist. Then if I change `.hgsubstate` like this:

```
d35a3fb7e627b5598fb763f480e3f76932cf4232 GWT_multiple_apps
```

So it directs on actual head of git repo, than when I clone my repo, I get this message:

```
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 10 changesets with 27 changes to 19 files
updating to branch default
cloning subrepo GWT_multiple_apps from https://georgy7@bitbucket.org/cube54/mavemples/git%3A//git%40bitbucket.org%3Aespinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup.git
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 10 changesets with 27 changes to 19 files
abort: unknown revision 'd35a3fb7e627b5598fb763f480e3f76932cf4232'!
```

And also, my hg subrepo's hgrc file contains this:

```
[paths]
default = https://georgy7@bitbucket.org/cube54/mavemples/git%3A//git%40bitbucket.org%3Aespinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup.git
```

If I remove `.hg` folder in subrepo folder, then clone git repo to subrepo folder, than TortoiseHg in commit dialog told me that subrepository deleted.

So I don't know what I gotta do at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to make git subrepo, update your hg. Make sure that *your hg* and git *are up to date* and installed in the proper way. Latter versions give more comprehensible error messages. When hg gives just `abort:` message only you can use options `--traceback --debug`. 
   For example `hg push --traceback --debug  https://someurl`
2. On bitbucket use `https` URL instead of `git@` one. You can copy-paste it from project web-page.
3. `.hgsubstate` revisions direct to subrepos' revisions.
4. If `.hgsub` is written properly, there will no `.hg` subfolder appear in your git subrepo folder.

My new `.hgsub`

```
GWT_multiple_apps = [git]https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup.git
```

`.hgsubstate`

```
d35a3fb7e627b5598fb763f480e3f76932cf4232 GWT_multiple_apps
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, re-read [Git subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Git_subrepositories) from Subrepository Wiki-page and remember format of `.hgsub` for foreign repo and sequence of operations (maybe BB-superrepo have to be re-created)

`nested = [git]git://example.com/nested/repo/path.git`